# managing multiple domains with multiple IPs in one server

Tags: centos, server, directadmin

i want to manage multiple android application in one dedicated server but with a different users and different IPs. so I've ordered a dedicated server with 16 IPs.
Os of this server is Cent Os and directadmin is installed on it.
how can i add these IPs to server and then add domains and users to them?(just got IPs and mac addresses as a txt file)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can add your all Ip's in your direct-admin panel through IP Management and you can assign them to your user which is created in your direct-admin panel.